# R Programming - Too Many Packages

Tags: r, r-package

It has been a month since I started working with R programming, and one thing which sets it apart from other statistical programming languages is large base of package support.

However, lately I realized that there are different packages for same task. Which to me raises questions around efficient usage of packages.

In all, I have following questions around packages in R programming:

- With more than [13K packages](https://www.rdocumentation.org/), how to choose correct package that provides useful features?
- Are all the packages being actively supported with new features and possible bugs?
- Someone like me who's new to R, might find it difficult to get hold of correct package initially. How to avoid this?
- Do package developer ensure that there might already be a package solving same problem? This may help avoid multiple packages doing same task.

Looking forward to answers/comments, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With more than 13K packages, how to choose correct package that provides useful features?

> Generally speaking if the package solves your problem then it is the right package to use.

Are all the packages being actively supported with new features and possible bugs?

> No, though if the package is in CRAN it is likely to be under active development if only minimally so.

Someone like me who's new to R, might find it difficult to get hold of correct package initially. How to avoid this?

> "Correct" package is ambiguous, see point #1. Stick to popular packages, read articles on R programming and most importantly talk to other R programmers to learn about new packages.

Do package developer ensure that there might already be a package solving same problem? This may help avoid multiple packages doing same task.

> No. Everyone has their way of doing things. Find a package that solves your problem and fits with your coding style and run with it.
>       --For example, I am not a `tidyverse` user, sometimes I use a function here or there but it is not part of by daily/usual workflow. There's nothing wrong with the package but its style of programming is not intuitive to me so I stay away it as best I can.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a list with the more used packages:

- https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201057987-Quick-list-of-useful-R-packages
- https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-50-most-used-r-packages/
- http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/06/top-20-r-packages.html

But when you are learning any computer language, you must learn what you need to use first.

Here you can find an app to visualise CRAN downloads:
https://github.com/hadley/cran-downloads